# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException even when setting new array length to old array length

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

This is a problem on CodingBat.com, "frontPiece". As explained on the problem, the return is supposed to be an array of the first two elements of the original array. That's no problem. However, a couple edge cases are an empty array and an array of one element. This is where I'm getting some errors.

The easy way to to do this is to have an IF statement for each of the edge cases. This seems facile to me and one reason I'm doing these exercises is to learn new tools, like the enhanced FOR loop.

````
  if(nums.length < 2){
    int[] answer = new int[nums.length];
    for(int x: nums){
      answer[x] = nums[x];
    }
    return answer;
  }else{
    int[] answer = new int[2];
    answer[0] = nums[0];
    answer[1] = nums[1];
    return answer;
  }
} ```
````

Most input arrays will fail the IF statement, falling through to the declaration and population of the new array in the ELSE part of the code. An empty array results in an empty array being created and returned, also passing. The error come with an array of size one.

My (possibly inadequate) understanding of the enhanced FOR or FOR EACH loop is that it steps through the array performing the code block below for each element therein. I would have thought that setting the ANSWER array's length to that of the original NUMS array would have prevented an OOB error.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in this loop

```
for(int x: nums)
```

you are not iterating over *indexes* of the `nums` array but over *values* so if value is bigger than `nums.length` you are out of the array boundaries

for example:

```
int nums[] = new int[]{1000};
```

however `nums.length` is `1` in the first iteration of the for-each loop you will try to access `answer[1000]` and `nums[1000]`

---

for such copying you should use `for(;;)` version of loop or even better `Arrays.copyOf()` method